# Unable to use output when using Terraform module with source set to git repository

Tags: terraform

I'm having difficulty using output when I use a git repository as the source for a module. It fails early during terraform init.

**This works**

Here I use the relative path to testmodule. I am able to run terraform init and terraform plan here.

```
main.tf
-------
...
module "vm" {
  source                 = "../../../../../module/testmodule"
  ...
}
output "test" { value = "${module.vm.testit}"}


module/testmodule/main.tf
------------------
...
output "testit" { value = "testit"}
```

**This does not work**

Here I use a git repository as the source.

When doing this and terraform init, i get this error.

```
terraform init
Initializing modules...
- module.vm

Initializing the backend...

Error: output 'test': "testit" is not a valid output for module "vm"


main.tf
-------
...
module "vm" {
  source                 = "git@github.com:MyInc/deploy.git?ref=4056f32afd3f146dbc53g8d1dsaa8e45c17c3db3//terraform/module/testmodule"
  ...
}
output "test" { value = "${module.vm.testit}"}


module/testmodule/main.tf
------------------
...
output "testit" { value = "testit"}
```

Comment: What terraform version are you using? git-sourced modules support outputs as you've described them above. I'd doublecheck the git ref and make sure that version of the module has the outputs defined.

Comment: After checking my work a bazillion times, I found that i was not using the correct git ref as you mentioned T_T Thanks @justMiles!!!